# Recommendations for a beginner using Playwright in C# for Blazer app

Tags: c#, nunit, playwright, vscode

I'm new to test automation and do not have a coding background. I need to create tests using Playwright in C# for a Blazer app. Can anyone recommend good resources to help me get started?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some resources that may be helpful:

1. Playwright Documentation

- https://playwright.dev/docs/intro

2. Playwright .NET Samples - Playwright .NET Samples repository has a set of sample code to help you get started with using Playwright in C#.

- https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/intro
- https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-dotnet
- https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-playwright

3. Blazor Documentation

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website
- https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/introduction

4. C# Programming Guide - If you are new to C#, the C# Programming Guide is a great resource for learning the language.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/

5. Pluralsight - Pluralsight is an online learning platform that offers courses on a variety of topics, including C# programming and Playwright.

- https://www.pluralsight.com/browse

6. Udemy - Udemy is another online learning platform that offers courses on Playwright and C# programming. They also have a wide range of courses on Blazor development.

- https://www.udemy.com/

7. YouTube - There are many YouTube channels that offer tutorials on Playwright, C# programming, and Blazor development. Some channels that you might find helpful include The Net Ninja, Tim Corey, and freeCodeCamp.

I hope these resources help you get started with Playwright in C# for your Blazor app! Good luck with your test automation journey!

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to reply and provide help